# How protocol is communicated between routers web-server and the browser

Tags: http, browser, network-programming, webserver

I'm working on an application which takes HTTP message to and from the routers web server.

The problem i'm facing is in the HTTP `basic authentication`.

[RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) states:
"*the server can reply with a challenge using the `401 (Unauthorized)` status code*"

What I've seen from the browser HTTP captures that it isn't the case for every router. For example, `TPLINK TLWR840N` doesn't sends me `401` and i can get the resource by simply transferring http request along with the correct credentials in the form of base64{username:pass} in the http message as shown below.

```
GET //main/ddos.htm?_=1572950350469 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://192.168.0.1
Cookie: Authorization=Basic YeRtaW46YWRtaW5AMTIz
```

It gives me the requested content if the password is correctly given otherwise it redirects me to the login page (why this router doesn't follow the `401` protocol?).

I have another `TPLINK TL-WR841N` router which doesn't take credentials (in http message) in the form of base64{username:pass} as the previous router, but instead it takes credentials in the form of base64(user):md5(password). I have two question about this router (*and all routers in general*)

1. I want to know how the router communicates the protocol for credentials to the browser so that i can embed that thing in my application. I have inspected the http messages (in the Chrome/Firefox) but couldn't found the message where the protocol is being communicated.
2. When i login to `TPLINK TL-WR841N` router, unlike the previous model, the web browser contains some SessionID in the URL, e.g. the URL shows `www.192.168.0.1/SessionID/path/to/resource`. I would like to know how this SessionID is communicated to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who write router maintenance applications, as well as people who design graphics cards driver installer screens (looking at you, AMD), do not adhere to any guidelines, best practices or protocols whatsoever.

But they don't need to, either. They've written an application that happens to use HTTP, but you're not obliged to use all of HTTP. They write the frond-end as well as the back-end, so they can closely control their server as well as their client.

The client most likely is a dumb couple of HTML pages that does some requests using JavaScript.

If they were to decide that the web interface authenticates to the server with a request header that literally states `LetMeIn: true`, then that would work as well.

HTTP does not mandate that the server should return a 401 when that header is missing or bears `false`, so they don't have to.